# Duplicate symbol error adding new library

Tags: c++, ns-3

working in the ns-3 environment, I have made a library where there are some methods called in my code. In order to compile the library I add in the wscript file the link to the library and I control if it is already define as follow:

```
#ifndef MY_LIBRARY_H_
#define MY_LIBRARY_H_

.. my methods

#endif
```

When I build the code this following error is generated:

```
duplicate symbol __Z8getValueiib in:
    src/model/bs-phy.cc.1.o
    src/model/ue-phy.cc.1.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think this is due to the fact that I use my methods in more then one class and maybe there are some error for multi-compiling. Any idea to solve the problems? (I'm not an expert and maybe I'm missing something!!!)

Thanks for the help!!

[EDIT]

```
uint32_t findOutSector()
{
    uint32_t sector = 0;
    return sector;
}
```

Comment: Show us what `.. my methods` is exactly! Without i can just guess that you defined your function in _my_library_ header and every include creates a new one, so on linking there's the same function in multiple objects.

Comment: @Youka thanks for your answer, I edited the question adding the method. The error appear also with this simple return method. About what you where saying before, in the case of multiple object, how I can fix or solve this???

Comment: @melpomene I simple write a .h code where I write methods to use in the classes as support.

Comment: @Mattia That's not how you create libraries. Headers should only contain function declarations, not definitions.

Comment: @melpomene I use to write everything in the .h
Thanks for your suggestion, I solved the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your function `findOutSector` written in the header directly? If yes, put the definition in a `.c` file (+ compile & link) and just the function declaration in the header. The function should just exist once in all compiled objects and the declaration serves as reference to it.

Comment: I use to write everything in the .h
Thanks for your suggestion, I solved the problem!!!